# Machine does not POST after non-os hdd format

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I recently purchased a new HDD. I installed it in my machine and booted it up. No problem. Formatted it GPT/exFAT in Windows and attempted to copy some data over from an old drive. Nothing appeared to happen, the copy appeared to not be in action. Figured I'd reboot. Now stuck before POST. The new drive heats up quite a bit, but nothing happens. I left it overnight in case it was scanning the drive and perhaps cached some drive metadata in CMOS.

I have tried:

- clearing CMOS per motherboard instructions
- unplugging other drives (is it consuming too much power?)
- booting the machine then plugging the drive in (cowboy behaviour- no idea if hot-swap is supported..)
- swapping cables with those from a correctly detected drive

I am currently using the machine with the problematic drive disconnected. It works just fine, as it did previously, when the drive is not connected.

The drive is a 4TB HGST Deskstar NAS (struggling to find a more detailed id, but can probably locate one if necessary). Motherboard is an ASRock Z87 Extreme3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I read my motherboard docs and discovered SATA hotplug is supported. But the setting was not obvious in my bios (it was per-port). After I eventually found and enabled it, I was able to hotplug the drive, rewrite the partition scheme (dunno if this is correct terminology, but readers will hopefully understand) and format the disk. The drive now works fine.

In case it helps future readers, it seems as though hotplug is likely available on most modern consumer motherboards. You may need to enable AHCI.

Comment: Does this solve the problem of over-heating?

Comment: I wouldn't say the drive was overheating, only that it was warm when my other drives weren't, suggesting it was doing something. Now they're all roughly the same temp to the touch.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple advice : If the disk plays havoc with Windows and if it is heating up
considerably when not in heavy use, the disk is probably defective.

A defective disk cannot be fixed. My suggestion is to use your warranty and have it replaced.

(Small remark: NTFS is much preferable to exFAT.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's not really having trouble under Windows at this stage, because it's not getting to Windows at all! I'll wait a while for any other responses before returning the drive. Thanks for the tip, I formatted exFAT for OSX compat.

Comment: Solved. I don't know what the problem was, but I've circumvented it. In case you're curious, see my answer. Thanks for your reply, anyway.